# Image with hover effect of text (link)

Tags: html, css, hover

I am a student and new to coding. I have an image and would like the actors name to appear in center of image as a clickable link to show as a hover effect. [This is what I want it to look like!](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_css_image_overlay_opacity) 
I tried the code that is listed on the link above but name will not show as link. [Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivNgY.png) since it's just a file on my computer.

I have included coding for two of the 10 images I will use.

HTML-

```
<div class="pics-container">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Bateman">
<img src="pics/Jason.jpg" alt="Jason Bateman" class="image" border="2px";>
</a><div class="middle"><div class="name">Jason Bateman</div></div>

<div class="pics-container">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_McAdams">
<img src="pics/Rachel.jpg" alt="Rachel McAdams" class="image" border="2px";>
</a><div class="middle"><div class="name">Rachel McAdams</div></div>
```

CSS-

```
.middle {
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 38%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
.pics-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 20px;
}
.pics-container:hover .image {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.pics-container:hover .middle {
  opacity: 1;
}

.name {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 16px 32px;
}
```

This is from me researching and trying to put the codes together. Also, after adding padding the images are now stair-stepped instead of being lined up.

Comment: Show us your attempt. Create a [MCVE] within your question.

Comment: copy that code and create a snippet here. Or share that code with your question. Don't give just a link.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai I rolled back your edit becasue that isn't OPs code. We want to see OPs attempt - not somebody else's.

Comment: @Turnip that's OK. I thought the code is he tried.

Comment: i'm pretty sure you could have googled this without having to write a stack overflow question, saying that though unless you've literally copy and pasted the linked example, we can't determine the problem until you've shown us your attempt.

Comment: Here is how I have it right now...                                                                      <div class="pics-container">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jason_Bateman">
<img src="pics/Jason.jpg" alt="Jason Bateman" class="image" border="2px";>
</a><div class="middle"><div class="name">Jason Bateman</div></div>

<div class="pics-container">
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rachel_McAdams">
<img src="pics/Rachel.jpg" alt="Rachel McAdams" class="image" border="2px";>
</a><div class="middle"><div class="name">Rachel McAdams</div></div>

Comment: @KMc you can edit your question using `edit` link and add your code.

Comment: I have edited question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Is this what u want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
    .image {
    opacity: 1;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transition: .5s ease;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .middle {
    transition: .5s ease;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
    }
    .img_hover:hover .image {
    opacity: 0.3;
    }
    .img_hover:hover .middle {
    opacity: 1;
    }
    .text {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 32px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br><br>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm img_hover">
          <img src="your_image" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
          <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">John Doe</div>
          </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col-sm img_hover">
          <img src="your_image" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
          <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">John Doe</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm img_hover">
          <img src="your_image" alt="Avatar" class="image" style="width:100%">
          <div class="middle">
            <div class="text">John Doe</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @Kevin!! It works. I just have to adjust columns and rows.

Comment: Without the link stylesheet, all images are in one row and names are not present, image is link.

Comment: Fixed it! Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Add anchor tag outside of name like this

```
<a href="#"><div class="text">John Doe</div></a>
```